# Image will not display when inside a tab, but will display outside of the tab

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to display an image in a tab widget in tkinter, however when I run the code the GUI is displayed however the image does not display in the tab, nor does it display anywhere and was hoping for some help. I made another .py file to test if the image displays outside of the tabs and it works fine, but when i try add the same code to the subroutine it no longer displays.

Here is the code in which it doesn't display: (only a snippet but this is where the issue is i assume)

```
def tabController():

    tabControl = ttk.Notebook(map)

    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl, width = 500, height = 540)
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl, width = 500, height = 540)

    tabControl.add(tab1, text="Ground Floor")
    tabControl.add(tab2, text="Second Floor")


    tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    ttk.Label(tab1)
    ttk.Label(tab2)

    frame = ttk.Frame(tabControl, width=600, height=400)
    frame.pack()
    frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.5)

    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('firstfloor.png'))

    label = ttk.Label(frame, image = img)
    label.pack()


tabController()
```

Then this is the other .py file in which it displays:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

map = Tk()
map.title('image test')
map.geometry("1000x1000")

frame = Frame(map, width=600, height=400)
frame.pack()
frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.5)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('firstfloor.png'))

label = Label(frame, image = img)
label.pack()

map.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a very subtle problem in Tk that should be considered a bug.  When you use `ImageTk.PhotoImage`, the framework does not take a reference to that object.  So, when your function exits, the object is deleted and the Label has nothing to display.  Try `global img` (or `tabController.img`) and it should work.  https://bugs.python.org/issue632323